# How to set the python environment for LaunchDaemons

Tags: mojave, homebrew, launchd, python, plist

I have installed Python 3 via Homebrew, on my Mojave system, and have it symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/python`.

I have a LaunchDaemon plist as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>test</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>python</string>
          <string>--version</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key><true/>

        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PATH</key>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
            <key>PYTHONPATH</key>
            <string>/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages</string>
        </dict>

        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/test.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/test_err.log</string>

    </dict>
</plist>
```

However, this still returns Python 2.7.10 which is installed by default on the Mojave system.

How do I set the path up for this LaunchDaemon so that is has access to the Python 3 environment instead?

---

Additional info:

For the full plist I am using, the program calls python at some point (python isn't the entry point), hence requiring the `PYTHONPATH` being set to point to the site-packages where some additional packages have been installed.

The error which pops up there is:

```
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x!
     PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"
     You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```

Comment: What is `/usr/local/bin/python3`? A file or a folder? Shouldn't the `PATH` variable be set to `/usr/local/bin` if your python binary is `/usr/local/bin/python`?

Comment: Oh, that's a file - I've tried setting it to just `/usr/local/bin` but had no luck with that...

Comment: Perhaps see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path

Comment: The answer could alter if you are not calling python directly - there could be issues with the calling script as well and also how it calls python

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use an absolute path in ProgramArguments, so

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>python</string>
```

would become

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
    ..........
```

Your PATH variable is not correct. Change it to

```
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
```

Comment: Note that if the script does not call an external command you don't need the PATH entry in the launch plist

Answer (score -1):

Since you have more than 1 python version on your machine you should definitely create [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) or [here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/). Create one for each version of python you have and then you can activate the virtual environment for whichever version of Python you wish to run.